# Android & iOS testing on win machine

Tags: android, ios, testing, appium

I just started to look around about mobile device automating testing 
It looks pretty interesting and right now I'm looking at testNg+Selenium+Appium ( not so bad) 
Didn't find any trouble till now with android but the iOS looks more "complicated" 
- Is it possible to test both systems on a win machine? 
- Is there some nice tool to get xpaths,id's, etc from iOS native applications?

Answer (score 0):

Appium inspector will give you all the information (ID, xpath, name etc.) You don't need to actually record the scripts to get that information, just launch the inspector and use the "screenshot" of you app to explore the elements and see how you can identify them. Accessibility Inspector in the iOS simulator will help you identify the elements like ids.